# Use sssd to join a redhat 7 machine to Active Directory domain without prompting the password

Tags: authentication, active-directory

How do I use sssd to join a Red Hat 7 machine to Active Directory domain without prompting the password? I am trying to automate the domain join.

```
realm join -U adjoin --client-software=sssd abc.com
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/314621/8945

Answer (score 1):

The `realm` manpage says:

> It is generally possible to use kerberos credentials to perform a join
>   operation. Use the kinit command to acquire credentials prior to
>   starting the join. Do not specify the --user argument, the
>          user will be selected automatically from the credential cache. The realm respects the KRB5_CCACHE environment variable, but uses the
>   default kerberos credential cache if it's not present. Not all
>          types of servers can be joined using kerberos credentials, some (like IPA) insist on prompting for a password.

So if I understand that right, just acquiring a Kerberos credential with `kinit` and not adding the `--useroption` should just work..