# Join Redhat 7 without prompting the password

Tags: rhel, password, active-directory, sssd

I am trying to automate domain join on RedHat 7 using the following command:

```
realm join -U serviceaccount --client-software=sssd abc.com
```

The problem is this command prompts for password which stops my script. How do I workaround so it doesn't prompt for the password? 
I need a solution which will definitely work.

Answer (score 4):

RE: There is not a workaround on the Red Hat side to get around someone entering a password either before or during the realm join.

There is always a work around in Linux/Unix:

```
echo $passwd| realm join -U serviceaccount --client-software=sssd abc.com
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

From a Red Hat perspective, you can run the `realm join` without a password, but it first requires you doing a `kinit serviceaccount` assuming Kerberos is properly configured.  See documentation [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Windows_Integration_Guide/realmd-domain.html).  There is not a workaround on the Red Hat side to get around someone entering a password either before or during the `realm join`.

There may be something that can be done on the AD side to not require a password when joining a domain, but that would be off-topic for this forum.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is kind of old, but there is an option available that doesn't necessarily require an AD account with password.  Both `realm` and `adcli` commands support the `--one-time-password` argument, however this requires that the computer objects are pre-created in Active Directory and that you know the Machine Account Password of the computer object.

You can use the Powershell cmdlet `Reset-ComputerMachinePassword` and/or possibly the `netdom reset` or `netdom resetpwd` commands on Windows to manually set the Machine Account password to a well-known string.  You can also use the Active Directory Users and Computers GUI to perform a `Reset Account` on the computer object in Active Directory - which changes the Machine Account password to match the computer object name (e.g. if the computer object is **WORKSTATION01** this changes the Machine Account Password to the string "WORKSTATION01").

In such a case, you can then join Linux machines to the domain using the hostname (or whatever you set using Reset-ComputerMachinePassword) as the one-time password, without needing credentials to an actual domain user/service account.

```
realm join <mydomain>.example.com --one-time-password `hostname -s`
```